# TypeScript declaration file for re-exported functions

Tags: typescript

I am writing a declaration file for a library that does not yet have TS types. This library has two JS files, an `index.js` and a `util.js`. `index.js` has multiple exported functions and also re-exports two functions from `util.js`.

My problem is that the TS compiler can't seem to pick up the type definitions for these re-exported functions. Below is my declaration file.

`index.d.ts`

```
// From `index.js`
export function baz() { ... }
...

// From `util.js`
export function foo() { ... }
export function bar() { ... }
```

Now, this can be remedied by moving `foo()` and `bar()` definitions into a `util.d.ts` file, and replacing them in the `index.d.ts` file with `export { foo, bar } from "./util.js";`. However, I don't want to do this. I want all definitions to be in the same file. Cleaner that way.